# Run JQuery animation on numbers when I scroll once on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an one-page-style website and somewhere in the middle I have a few numbers as statistics. I try to make them counting until they reach the stats when a user find the div for the first time after refreshing the page. I don't have the option to use a plugin, so I am trying to do it with JQuery only.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $("#our-company").offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $("#our-company").height();

    if ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {
       start_count();
    }
});

function start_count(){
    $('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
}
```

The div with the `id = our-company` is the one containing the stats and all the numbers are in a span with a class of `class = count`. The problem in my code is that after I scrolled down on the stats and see the numbers counting, if I scroll up and down again, they start from the beginning. How can I make it run once?

Comment: "I try to make them counting until they reach the stats when a user find the div for the first time after refreshing the page"...did not understand anything :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put a flag var ?

```
var alreadyRun = false;
[...]
 if (alreadyRun == false && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {
   alreadyRun = true;
   start_count();
}
[...]
```

Cheers